# How to see that this sum vanishes?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967.pdf).

On page 15, it is claimed that
$$
\small{
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j (\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j-f_{ij}^{n+1})f_{ij}^{n+1}\gamma_j = -\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j (f_{ij}^{n+1}-\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j)^2\gamma_j\tag{1}}
$$
follows from the definition of $\rho_i^{n+1}$, which is
$$
\rho_i^{n+1}=\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\Delta v_j f_{ij}^{n+1}\tag{2},
$$
and the unit mass assumption on the discrete Maxwellians, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\Delta v_j M_j=1\tag{3}.
$$

I do not see it completely. How does (1) follow by (2) and (3)?

---

Since $(f_{ij}^{n+1})^2-\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j f_{ij}^{n+1}=(f_{ij}^{n+1}-\rho_i^{n+1} \mathcal{M}_j)^2+f_{ij}^{n+1}\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j-(\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j)^2$, I get
$$
\small{
\begin{align*}
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j (\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j-f_{ij}^{n+1})f_{ij}^{n+1}\gamma_j&= -\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j(f_{ij}^{n+1}-\rho_i^{n+1} \mathcal{M}_j)^2\gamma_j\\
&\quad - \underbrace{\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j(f_{ij}^{n+1}\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j-(\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j)^2)\gamma_j}_{A}
\end{align*}}
$$

But I don't see that $A=0$ so that the claim follows. Probably, this is where (2) and (3) come into play.

I just end at
$$
A=\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j \rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j(f_{ij}^{n+1}-\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j)\gamma_j
$$

I tried to plug in (2), but this did not give me anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the original paper, it seems the definition of $\gamma_j$ on page 12 is significant here too, as it's $\gamma_j = \frac{1}{\mathcal{M}_j}$. That means your $A$ becomes :
\begin{align*}
A
&= \sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}} \Delta x_i \Delta v_j \rho^{n+1}_i (f_{ij}^{n+1} - \rho^{n+1}_i \mathcal{M}_j) \\
&= \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} \Delta x_i \rho^{n+1}_i (\underbrace{\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \Delta v_j f^{n+1}_{ij}}_{=\rho^{n+1}_i} - \rho^{n+1}_{i} \underbrace{\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \Delta v_j \mathcal{M}_j}_{=1})
= 0.
\end{align*}